# How to install a plugin in Teamcity

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, teamcity

i want to download sonarqube plugin for teamcity. Documentation says i can download it from  [TeamCity Server](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/project.html?projectId=TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_TeamCitySonarQubePlugin&tab=projectOverview)
But how? Where is the zip file? Where can i download it from??
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can expect to find plugins on the [TeamCity plugin repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/teamcity), but for some reason, author decided to put it to official JetBrains Teamcity server.

So, you have to go to [`teamcity.jetbrains.com`](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/project.html?projectId=TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_TeamCitySonarQubePlugin), login as guest, select build for your Teamcity version (10.x or 9.x), click on the latest build and switch to artifacts tab, where you can download the zip, containing the plugin.

Here is the [link](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/repository/download/TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_TeamCitySonarQubePlugin_Build100x/940931:id/sonar-plugin.zip) for 10.x plugin for your convenience.

Comment: thanks for the link! and should i copy the zip file directly to the C: Teamcity: plugins path?

Comment: Yes, after you downloaded the plugin, you should drop the zip into the `<TeamCity Data Directory>/plugins` directory and restart the server. Here is the [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Installing+Additional+Plugins) to official documentation.